# How do I change email senders avatar in smtp C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I have been able to modify the senders name but I want to change the avatar that displays when viewing the mail.
Please note that am using smtp.
Will appreciate snippets in C# or VB.
By the way its an asp mvc 5 project.

Comment: Any Avatar is displayed at the receiving end. There is no "sender avatar" in SMTP. (When SMTP was defined GUIs were just about beginning to appear, but most users were on text only terminals.)

Comment: Thanks at @Richard,so any idea how, yahoo, twitter etc logos display on the avatar section without me having to save them as contacts..? The default I see is the first letter of the senders name

Comment: It'll likely be a user setting which the client uses. Ie. if there is a user with the from email that has an avatar set then use that avatar.

Comment: Thanks alot @Richard, unfortunately for me, I can't see the option of modifying the avatar as it's not available on the custom email generated by goddady.. Should I be wrong, I will appreciate some insight.

Comment: Exactly. The sender has no control. It is a email client feature.